# Debug iOS Apps - Kony Studio - failed to get tabs for debugging connection refused kony

Tags: temenos-quantum

trying to debug iOS Kony projects using Kony studio, have created a new cofiguration according to the tutorial from Kony bootcamp, I am not able to run the project in debug mode, I am getting the below error messages. Attached is the screen shots for reference.

error message :- Failed to get tabs for debugging connection refused

[image]

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the below,
first build the project.

Then open the iOS emulator  from the studio, by double click on iPhone, this will fire up the    xCode project ( make sure xcode is installed )

Run the project from  xCode by choosing debug option from the drop down in xCode, using any    simulator like iPhone, this will launch the app in the simulator with    alert showing to enter the debugger host port. ( i gave the port as    9222 )

click on start and then you will see message as waiting for Kony studio to connect.

Now go back to your Kony studio and right    click on the project and debug as iOS application, ( make sure you    have configure a configuration in studio and ip address and port   matches the same with iOS simulator details ) doing this will launch    in debug mode and you will be able to add break points wherever    required.